# same height of youtube video tumbnail images (3 columns) in one row

Tags: wordpress, video, height, divi

same height of youtube video tumbnail images (3 columns) in one row. I have 3 deffrent video (3 columns) in one row. I would like to have the same height of thumbnail video. How can I make these 3 video in the same height? I used video module for 3 columns

Comment: Since you say you have thumbnail images, you can simply add this css: `img{height:100px}`

Comment: please add some detail like screenshots or layout code to the question